# Javascript return something from replaceWith

Tags: javascript, dom, replace

I have created a javascript web component where one element is completely replaced with a set of html elements.

To do that I use `replaceWith`. My problem is that I need to keep track of the new created element. How can I do that? I use vanilla js ES6, not jQuery.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('div');
let another = document.querySelector('h2');
  
element.replaceWith(another);
```

```html
<div>
Replace this content
</div>

<h2>Heading 1</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 3</h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n9q0x86a/1/

Comment: But... you're already keeping track. Your variables... What was the question again?

Comment: `My problem is that I need to keep track of the new created element.` - which is accessible via `another`...?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `keep track of the new created element` but assuming you want to target the replaced elements after, just add a unique ID to each of them or to a wrapper div and target that/those id after.

Comment: Also, do you realize that only the first H2 is being moved?

Comment: but why can't you use the `another` variable? that's the new one

Comment: You can mantain a `counter` variable for each replaceWith(another). I think you are saying like `Arrays.asList(some_list) in java will change the behaviour completely and wont return to its original behaviour`. In this case you want so that u need the previous one as well so what you can do is temporarily store that component before replacing

Comment: @AndrewL Yes thanks! I'm however hoping there is a way to not add any additonal html.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes. I just wanted to show that there may be more than one element, makes it harder to get the element after the replacement.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja That's the best idea I've read so far. It will not add additional HTML and may still work. Thanks!

Comment: Great if it works for you @Jens. You're Welcome :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, your comment was the real solution to my problem. Why it did not work to do a console.log on that element was because it was a documentFragment at the moment (not visibile by my example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have created a javascript web component where one element is completely replaced with a **set of html elements***

your statement is wrong, if you want to move **all** the desired elements in place of `<div>`. In such case you need to use the [`querySelectorAll()`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method. Which in turn will give you I believe exactly what you expect: **a collection of all our targeted selectors**:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#replaceMe');
const another = document.querySelectorAll('.moveMe');
  
element.replaceWith(...another);
console.log("Replaced #%s with %i elements", element.id, another.length);

// let's try to manipulate our stored elements:
[...another].forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<div data-info="This DIV should stay">
  <div id="replaceMe" data-info="this DIV should be replaced">
  Replace this content
  </div>
</div>

<h1 class="moveMe">Heading 1</h2>
<h2 class="moveMe">Heading 2</h2>
<p class="moveMe">Paragraph</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @AndrewL take a closer look at my example. I don't get what you're talking about. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, I think he rushed to fiddle instead of inspecting the above snippet.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I just noticed the spread syntax that you used yes. My apologies. But I don't get how `replaceWith()` managed to replaced the div with all the elements even though `querySelector` returns only the first matched element.

Comment: @AndrewL please come to me, I'm making coffee :) Look closer, I use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I do know that. querySelector only returns the first match element as I mentioned in the comment above yours. Which is why I dont understand how replaceWith() still populates the div with all three h2s in my jsfiddle.

Comment: @AndrewL in OP example only the first element is being moved! the remaining two h2 were there all the time. The exact reason I created another DIV wrapper to confirm he must use `querySelectorAll`! *DIV H2 **H2 H2*** becomes *h2 **H2 H2***

Comment: @Roko I'm not questioning your answer anymore. I noticed the spread syntax and retracted my downvote. But what I'm talking about now is this: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/ox1kj82b/14/

Comment: If you check the fiddle, all three h2s are retrieved even though I used querySelector and not querySelectorAll.

Comment: I'm not questioning YOUR CODE anymore. I'm questioning the behavior I got on the jsFiddle.

Comment: Oh I get it. Only one h2 moved inside the div but I was focusing on the visual output and forgot that it'll look the same regardless. My apologies yet again. I need some sleep.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I honestly don't see any of my comments as a "hissy fit" tbh and I even extended my apologies just after two comments when I realised that he used spread syntax. Weirdly enough, you were actually the one with the "hissy fits" as you called it questioning my eye sight when I already extended the apology like 4 comments above the eyesight comment that you deleted :) And I'll definitely upvote Roko yes. Thanks for being such a gentleman and recommending that mate :)

Comment: Be kind to each other! Thanks to all that made a comment here! =)